# Installing AX 2012 R2 KB item to R3

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, hotfix

We are running Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3 CU8.

Our customer wants to start using the rolecenter, but we found problems around importing Web URI into the AOT. There is a hofix for this (KB2894068), but it is for R2. The Microsoft LCS titles it: 'Error message is displayed when importing web URL page in AOT ”The parameter PageUrl is missing or invalid”'

I was wondering if there are 'Best Practices' on how to install an R2 hotfix in R3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is code only, meaning it isn't a kernel hotfix, then you only need to be concerned about merging the code into your environment. You don't want to overwrite R3 code if it isn't necessary for your fix.

There should be an impact analysis tool or a way to use the compare tool to see what code will change. Or, sometimes LCS will show you what the code changes are before you download the hotfix.